# PanacheMongo persistOrUpdate() The DBRef $ref field must be followed by a $id field

Tags: java, mongodb, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I'm getting this error:

```
com.mongodb.MongoWriteException: The DBRef $ref field must be followed by a $id field
```

when I want to update an already persisted Model in my mongodb with panache.

My model class:

```
@MongoEntity
public class MyModel extends PanacheMongoEntity {
...
}
```

I am using the auto-generated ID field if that helps anything.

When I update, I want to load the payload (which is a rather big json-file) from the database because it does not get sent by the frontend.

This is the smallest testcase I could produce that doesn't work:

```
@Transactional
public void myMethod(String id, MyModelDTO dto) {
    MyModel old = MyModel.findById(new ObjectId(id));
    dto.setPayload(old.getPayload());
    MyModel.update(mapper.toEntity(dto));
}
```

If I omit the `findById` method I do not get the error I mentioned in the top.
The dto has the id set as well, so the resulting `MyModel` has the correct ObjectId which was my first guess...

How can I fix this?
Is loading rather big chunks of data from the database into the DTO even a good solution? Or is there any other way I can update the whole object but one variable?

Comment: Where and how are you using DBRefs?

Comment: I don't use them anywhere intentionally.

Comment: I imagine you need to figure this out.

Comment: My model class does not use a DBref field, it has an ObjectId as id. I am extending PanacheMongoEntity which also should not use a com.mongo.DBRef field, so I really have no clue where the error comes from

Comment: If i load the model int variably `oldModel`, make some changes, reassign it to `newModel`  and then delete the `oldModel` and persist `newModel` it works, also transfers the id and everything. I don't really get that behavior.

Comment: I suggest either going through documentation of software you are using searching for DBRef or going through the source code. Either you configured something to use it or you have some software that goes out of its way to try to be helpful.